# Why are contravariant functors called contravariant?

Tags: category-theory, terminology

I'm just now learning a bit of category theory, and there often seems to be a certain notion, like limits for instance, and if you inverse certain arrows, you obtain a co-object related to that notion (for instance colimits).

Why is it, then, that we speak of contravariant functors instead of co-functors?

Comment: Tradition. ${}{}$

Comment: Probably at least in part this is by analogy with the terminology of *covariant* and *contravariant* tensors in linear algebra, which predates category theory by about a century: The earliest citation in the O.E.D. for *contravariant* dates to 1853 (from the work of Sylvester, in fact).

Comment: It also makes sense linguistically.  Variant as an adjective means "tending to change," so a covariant function is one which "changes with" while a contravariant functor is one which "changes against."

Comment: Thanks @Charlie . This makes a whole lot of sense.

Comment: ... because "cocovariant" is an awful word?

Comment: @EricTowers Yet we're happy to talk about coconuts. I've never heard of a contranut. :-)

Answer (score 14):

The definition of a functor is self-dual. If you reverse all the arrows in the definition of a functor $\mathsf{C} \to \mathsf{D}$, what you get is a functor $\mathsf{C}^\mathrm{op} \to \mathsf{D}^\mathrm{op}$, which is exactly the same thing as a functor $\mathsf{C} \to \mathsf{D}$. So in this sense a cofunctor is just a functor.

Now a contravariant functor is a functor too, but between different categories: a contravariant functor $\mathsf{C} \to \mathsf{D}$ is the same thing as a functor $\mathsf{C}^\mathrm{op} \to \mathsf{D}$, which is exactly the same thing as a functor $\mathsf{C} \to \mathsf{D}^\mathrm{op}$. This is rather unrelated to functors $\mathsf{C} \to \mathsf{D}$.

Note that some people *do* use the words "cofunctor" for contravariant functors, I guess it's just a matter of taste as long as every word is defined.

Comment: Interesting answer.

Comment: Worth to add that e.g. a comonad is _not_ the same a monad, despite the underlying functor/co-functor being the same.

Comment: Shouldn’t a cofunctor rather go $D^{op}\to C^{op}$?

Comment: @EmilJeřábek no in fact. It's the morphisms of the categories which are turned around when switching to the dual; the arrow _between_ the category is not considered a morphism at that level. (You could of course consider cofunctors on the _functor_ category; but then you'd simply be dealing with morphisms (functors!) $D\to C$... _as well as_ $C\to D$.)

Answer (score 4):

The dual functor of a functor $F: \mathbb{A} \rightarrow \mathbb{B}$ is the functor $F^\mathrm{op}: \mathbb{A}^\mathrm{op}\rightarrow \mathbb{B}^\mathrm{op}$ defined in the obvious way. So, for a duality principle, we would not define co-functors as contravariant functors.